# My smartphone is running an old Android GKI (v5.4). How can I install an updated GKI (like v5.10)?

Tags: android-kernel

I have a Xiaomi Mi Mix Fold, running MIUI 12 / Android 11.
The settings say that the running kernel version is 5.4.86-qgki-g629683a5515c.

I know that the purpose of the Android GKI is that the kernel can be updated without having to update the rest of the device. Does this mean I can download a newer Android GKI from Google, and install it?